# Why is antlr 4 Lexer.getCharPositionInLine() incorrectly returning 0?

Tags: antlr4

My understanding of the antlr 4 Lexer.getCharPositionInLine() function is that it is supposed to return the "character position within the line at which the token's first character occurs counting from zero" --The Definitive Antlr 4 Reference

Using the following antlr 4 grammar, it seems that the Lexer function getCharPositionInLine() always returns 0.  Notice the Java code in the COMMENT lexer rule.  It contains code to print the value returned from getCharPositionInLine().

```
grammar Expr;

compilUnit : stat+ EOF ;
stat : assign NEWLINE ;

assign : IDENT ASSIGN INT ;

// Lexer rules
ASSIGN : '=' {System.out.println(getLine() + ":" + getCharPositionInLine() + " /" + getText() + "/");} ;

APOS : '\'' {System.out.println(getLine() + ":" + getCharPositionInLine() + " /" + getText() + "/");} ;

INT : ('0' | '-'? [1-9][0-9]*) {System.out.println(getLine() + ":" + getCharPositionInLine() + " /" + getText() + "/");} ;

IDENT : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {System.out.println(getLine() + ":" + getCharPositionInLine() + " /" + getText() + "/");} ;


/* For lines that have only a comment preceeded by optional white space,
 * skip the entire line including the newline.  For lines that have a
 * comment preceeded by other code skip the comment and return a
 * NEWLINE. */
COMMENT : [ \t]* APOS NEND* END
    {
        int line = getLine();
        int pos = getCharPositionInLine();
        System.out.println("COMMENT " + line + ":" + pos + " /" + getText() + "/");
        if (pos == 0) {
            skip();
        }
        else {
            setType(NEWLINE);
            setText("\n");
        }
    }
    ;

NEWLINE : END+ {System.out.println(getLine() + ":" + getCharPositionInLine() + " /" + getText() + "/");} ;

WS : [ \t]+ {System.out.println(getLine() + ":" + getCharPositionInLine() + " /" + getText() + "/"); skip();} ;

fragment END : '\u000c'? '\r'? '\n' ;
fragment NEND : ~[\u000c\r\n] ;
```

I use these three commands from the command line:

```
java -jar antlr/antlr-4.1-complete.jar Expr.g4
javac -cp antlr/antlr-4.1-complete.jar Expr*.java
java -cp "antlr/antlr-4.1-complete.jar;." org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig Expr compilUnit -tokens progs/hello.laf
```

and for this input:

```
'Yo
x = 3  'Yay
```

I get this output:

```
COMMENT 2:0 /'Yo
/
2:1 /x/
2:2 / /
2:3 /=/
2:4 / /
2:5 /3/
COMMENT 3:0 /  'Yay
/
[@0,4:4='x',<4>,2:0]
[@1,6:6='=',<1>,2:2]
[@2,8:8='3',<3>,2:4]
[@3,16:15='<EOF>',<-1>,3:0]
line 3:0 missing NEWLINE at '<EOF>'
```

It appears that because the COMMENT lexer rule includes matching a newline character that the lexer has already incremented the line number by one and reset the character position to 0.  However, this doesn't match what the documentation in "The Definitive Antlr 4 Reference" says.  What am I doing wrong?  Or is this a bug in Antlr 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing [`Token.getCharPositionInLine()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html#getCharPositionInLine%28%29) with [`Lexer.getCharPositionInLine()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html#getCharPositionInLine%28%29). The latter returns the current lexer position, which for the case of your action is obviously always 0 because your action is placed immediately after a required newline.